# Combining .each and .change functions

Tags: jquery

I have multiple text inputs on a HTML page with the class="min_value", I need to add some validation to these text inputs with jQuery, the basic validation is shown, essentially is a value is entered below 250.00 the value of the textbox is set to 250.00 .

This works well with a single text input with the class "min_value" but not when multiple text inputs exist with the class name. Is it possible to alter this code so the validation is done on each text input, and only the value of that text input is changed?

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(".min_value").each(function(){

        $(".min_value").change(function(){ 

            var min_value = $(".min_value").val();

            if(min_value <= 250){
                $(".min_value").val('250.00');  
                alert('The Minimum Value can not be less the 250.00');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In the change handler you need to refer to the current element, you can use the `this` reference for that. Also there is no need of the `each` loop. `jQuery(function($) {
  $(".min_value").change(function() {
    var min_value = $(this).val();
    if (min_value <= 250) {
      $(this).val('250.00');
      alert('The Minimum Value can not be less the 250.00');
    }
  });
});`

Comment: You can't loop an event encapsulating it. In DOM, jQuery bind the event to the selectors rule you have passed simply. That's fired when triggered by 'selector' vs 'type of event' like click, change, focus or anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.min_value').on('input', function() {
     if((this).val() <= 250){
           $(this).val('250.00');  
           alert('The Minimum Value can not be less the 250.00');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`  object.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".min_value").change(function(){ 
        var min_value = $(this).val();
        if(min_value <= 250){
            $(this).val('250.00');  
            alert('The Minimum Value can not be less the 250.00');
        }
    });
});
```